# PHP5.3 htmlentities with ENT_HTML5 throws error message

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities

I recieve data from post form and want do store it in MySQL
the code line for handling the input is:

```
$tekst = $_POST["tekst"];
$tekst = htmlentities($tekst, ENT_QUOTES, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

When I run this I get the error message:
Warning: htmlentities(): charset `ENT_HTML5' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1 in savepage.php on line 14 index.php?id=1&ret=1 1

How do I overcome the warning?

Comment: `ENT_HTML5` was introduced into 5.4, How do I overcome the warning.. update php

Comment: What is the PHP version you are running ?

Comment: @Begueradj look at the title, PHP5.3

Comment: Sidenote, you should not be sanitizing/encoding your input data for storing, this should be done when you output. If you trying to protect from sql injections then your doing it wrong.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ how do you know ?

Comment: @Begueradj look at the title, PHP5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that error because you used the flag `ENT_HTML5` which appeared only in **PHP5.4.0**.

As you can confirm this from the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

> **5.4.0**     The constants ENT_SUBSTITUTE, ENT_DISALLOWED, ENT_HTML401, ENT_XML1, ENT_XHTML and **ENT_HTML5** were added.

If your only  goal is to overcome that error, then you can simply let the flags of the `htmlentities()` function not set.  Let PHP to treat them by default.

I mean, change this:

```
$tekst = htmlentities($tekst, ENT_QUOTES, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

To:

```
$tekst = htmlentities($tekst, "UTF-8");
```

An other option, is to set replace them with other flags supported by **PHP5.3.0**, such as:

- `ENT_COMPAT` : *Default. Encodes only double quotes*
- `ENT_IGNORE` : *Ignores invalid encoding instead of having the function return an empty string. Should be avoided, as it may have security implications.*